# Flutter- Using for loops or lists to create custom widgets with editable properties

Tags: list, loops, flutter, dart, generate

I created a custom class, RectButton, with editable properties of buttonChild, bgColor, and onPress. I was hoping to make this widget further dynamic by creating a new widget that can create a row of these RectButtons based on a variable integer (i.e. 4 buttons on one screen, 3 on another screen, etc) but cant figure out how to continue to have completely editable properties (bgColor isn't depended on index, i.e. bgColor: Colors.red[100 + 100 * index]) in the new widget.

```
class RectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RectButton({this.buttonChild, this.bgColor, this.onPress});

  final Widget buttonChild;
  final Color bgColor;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 100, height: 50),
        child: Center(child: buttonChild),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any thoughts? Any help is much appreciated. Ive been googling everything I can find about for loops and lists with no luck. Also any resources are also appreciated-- kinda new to flutter :)

Edit: Updated Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'rect_button.dart';

enum Options { option0, option1, option2, option3 }

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  List<Widget> makeButtons(int num, List<Widget> children, List<Color> colors,
      List<Function> onPresses) {
    List<Widget> buttons = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      buttons.add(RectButton(children[i], colors[i], onPresses[i]));
    }
    return buttons;
  }

  Options selectedOption;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int num = 2;
    List<Widget> children = [
      Text("A"),
      Text("B"),
    ];
    List<Color> colors = [
      selectedOption == Options.option0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      selectedOption == Options.option1 ? Colors.red : Colors.green
    ];
    List<Function> onPresses = [
      () {
        setState(() {
          selectedOption = Options.option0;
        });
      },
      () {
        setState(() {
          selectedOption = Options.option1;
        });
      },
    ];
// 3rd method does nothing
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: makeButtons(3, children, colors, onPresses),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the color IS dependent?

Comment: Yes sorry, Sidak. Good catch! I am hoping that each generated button would be independent of the other. Such that, one could be purple and one could be red if desired.

Comment: So you want something like, `makeButtonRow(int num, [Children], [Colors], [onPress])`?

Comment: Yes as long as that would allow me to produce varying numbers of RectButtons based on the int inputed into the makeButtonRow and allow me to change the Children, Colors, and onPress for each RectButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create Lists for each child, color, onPress you want, you can use the code below to loop through and create a list of `RectButton`:

```
List<Widget> makeButtons(int num, List<Widget> children, List<Color> colors, List<Function> onPresses){
  List<Widget> buttons = new List();
  for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++){
    buttons.add(RectButton(buttonChild: children[i], bgColor: colors[i], onPress: onPresses[i]));
  }
  return buttons;
}
```

You can use it with a `Row` like:

```
Row(
  children: makeButtons(...),
),
```

You can also modify the `makeButtons` method to add optional parameters in case you want one color consistently/with a [100+100*i] difference etc.

Edit: Example with build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int num = 2;
    List<Widget> children = [Text("A"), Text("B"), Text(_counter.toString())];
    List<Color> colors = [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.green];
    List<Function> onPresses = [_incrementCounter, _decrementCounter, (){}];
// 3rd method does nothing
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
      children: makeButtons(3, children, colors, onPresses),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks so much! Your code has definitely helped me to a lot. I am still running into some trouble though. Currently when I try and call the makeButtons, I keep getting the error "The argument type 'List<Widget>' can not be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'. Here is the code I was playing with: 



`Center(
        child: makeButtons(
          2,
          [Text('hi'), Text('helo')],
          [Colors.orange, Colors.red],
          [print('byeee'), print('eat me')],
        ),
      ),`

Comment: You need to call `makeButtons` in a `Row` or `Column` or `Stack` like structure where it requires children, not a single child. Alternatively, store the buttons like, `List<Widget> buttons = makeButtons(...)` and put the child of your container as `buttons[0]` etc.

Comment: Okay after some playing with the code I got it to work without any errors! Now when I run my code, there is nothing that is produced. Do I need to use a Listview.builder? or List.generate?

Comment: After some dabbling, I believe the buttons are not displaying secondary to the onPresses. I cant put a normal function (with void) or a future state inside the onPresses list as I get "the expression here has type "void/future" and therefore cant be used." I was able to do ```() {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = Options.option0;
                    });
                  },``` but it will not display the buttons.

Comment: Hey Peter, I just edited the code above to account for the optional arguments. I didn't realise that `RectButton` takes optional args. I've also tried to run the code and it works for me. You can check it out at https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Comment: I think that link is just to a normal dart pad. I only see the floating action button and the text that keeps track of number of times pushed :(

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited my answer with the code I used in `build()`

Comment: Sidak, I managed to figured out how to compile the code and remove errors. Unfortunately, I am still only getting an AppBar without the production of buttons. I edited my original post to reflect my full code. Do you see anything I am doing wrong? I did play with the 'num' but even with the corrections, I still had no buttons

Comment: Have a look at my `makeButtons` implementation. Your `makeButtons` is using the old implementation which doesnt work

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I truly appreciate your patience. Thanks again Sidak!